# Qt doesn't work in CLion because of missing dll file

Tags: c++, qt, clion

I've been trying for 2 days to get Qt to work in CLion and it seems like I get one error after the other. After following the tutorial from JetBrains and looking at like 20 other stack overflow questions related to the previous problems I had, I finally got to the point where I can build a project (I couldn't even hit the build button before). The problem now is that I get a build error. To make sure I got the other things right, this is where I currently am: I set MinGW from Qt as the default Toolchain (with the path as `C:\Qt\Tools\mingw810_64`) and I created a new project using the CLion option of creating a Qt Console Executable with Qt version 5. I provided the Qt CMake prefix path (which is `C:\Qt\5.15.2\mingw81_64\lib\cmake`) and hit Create. A new project is built, it finally lets me build it. But when I hit Build I get this error:

```
Error copying file "C:/Qt/5.15.2/mingw81_64/lib/cmake/../../bin/Qt5Cored.dll" to "D:/Some_directory/first_qt_project/cmake-build-debug".
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\first_qt_project.dir\build.make:124: first_qt_project.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** Deleting file 'first_qt_project.exe'
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:96: CMakeFiles/first_qt_project.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:103: CMakeFiles/first_qt_project.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:137: first_qt_project] Error 2
```

I had no idea what this is, but by reading it I understand that some .dll is missing. I searched other questions on stackoverflow and other people seemed to solve this by copying that .dll. The problem is, I don't have that dll on my system. I even performed a system search, but `Qt5Cored.dll` is nowhere to be found. On the other hand I found the dll `Qt5Core.dll` (without the `d` at the end) and copied that to the directory that CLion said it wanted to copy, but it still didn't work. I added a new environment path variable with the path `C:\Qt\5.15.2\mingw81_64\bin`, but this didn't solve it either. Neither did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59440037/15033320). I looked at some other questions regarding this problem, but those didn't help either. I feel like I've tried everything there is, but I still can't get this thing to work.

Comment: I looked, it appears the mingw builds do not have separate debug and release dlls. I expect whatever you are doing expects msvc instead of mingw as your compiler.

Comment: @drescherjm Ok, at least that's a lead. Can you please tell me what I should try to do in this case? Can I just change to msvc in CLion? Do I need to reinstall Qt with msvc instead of mingw? Or what do you think I should do, if you don't mind me asking. I'm very confused, I feel like I tried everything.

Comment: I think you should start out using Qt-Creator first unless this is a class requirement to use CLion.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem.But I had solved it!
The `Qt5cored.dll` be contained in `msvc` compiler. `MinGw` don't have it!
So,You need to install `msvc` compiler in `QtCreator Installer`.
And then, change folder which is `msvc`.(Such as `D:/Your install folder/mvsc2019_64/bin`)